# Passing by Reference and Forming References in C++98 and C++11

Tags: templates, c++11, reference, pass-by-reference, c++98

The following function works in C++11:

```
/**
* @brief Enqueue a data item in the PQ with given priority.
*
* @param data Data item to insert into PQ
* @param priority Priority level of item
*/
void enqueueWithPriority(const T& data, const PT priority) {

    size_t sizeVec = dataWithPriorityVec.size();

    // push the pair of data parameters to the end of the data vector
    dataWithPriorityVec.push_back(std::make_pair<const T&, const PT&>(data, priority));

    // call bubble up to sort data priorities
    bubbleUpHeap(sizeVec);

}
```

However it does not work in C++98 as I have to alter the `std::make_pair` part to: `std::make_pair<const T, const PT>` due to the inability to "store" references in 98. Similar syntax occurs in several other functions across my template class (where `T` and `PT` are generic typenames).

Is there a way I can resolve the issue such that I can use a single form of syntax as the former way works in C++11 but not 98 whereas the latter works in C++98 but not 11 - and I need to test in both environments unfortunately.

Comment: The `priority` parameter is not passed by reference.  Is this intentional?

Comment: *"the latter works in C++98 but not 11"*, just use `std::make_pair(data, priority)`, as C++11 appends `&&` to types given in a template arguments list

Comment: Are you trying to make `dataWithPriorityVec` be a `vector` of `pair`s of **references**?

Comment: No, this is how it is defined: `std::vector< std::pair<T, PT> > dataWithPriorityVec`. Also PT is not passed by reference as it is intended for this to be a primitive type rather than an object.